# Why are there always two primes between $2^n$ and $2^{n+1}$?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, cryptography

In a cryptographic lecture we just assumed that this statement holds. In particular, we said for a fixed length of bits one can always find two primes, that have the same length in binary representation. But why so? Is there an easy explanation I just overlooked or is the matter a bit more complicated?

I guess it follows from Bertrand's postulate, but I don't see how we get the second prime in this interval.

Edit: Of course this statement only holds for a large enough n, meaning $n\geq2$

Comment: See for instance the explicit improvements on the Wikipedia page of Bertrand’s postulate. I think the classical proof with $\binom{2n}{n}$ is also amenable to such an improvement.

Comment: The title is a bit misleading as I believe you meant "always at least two primes".

Comment: @DietrichBurde Do you not consider $2$ and $3$ to be primes for some reason? I think we can safely say there are *exactly* two primes in $[2^1,2^2]=[2,4]$.

Comment: @EricSnyder I thought of "between" as $2^n<p<2^{n+1}$ - for some reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This follows from a strengthening of Bertrand's postulate. In fact it can be shown that for every $\varepsilon>0$, for all sufficiently large $n$ there exists a prime between $n$ and $(1+\varepsilon)n$: See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_postulate#Better_results).

In particular, for any $k$ there are at least $k$ primes between $2^n$ and $2^{n+1}$ for sufficiently large $n$.

Comment: "*In particular, for $\epsilon =$*" should be $\epsilon = \sqrt{2}-1$ to have $(1+\epsilon)((1+\epsilon)n)=2n$

Comment: But do cryptographers rely on such asymptotic arguments? Is there no known prove that shows the claim rigorously?

Comment: @JMoravitz You are right, I have removed this ugly detail :)

Comment: @kerf "*But do bakers know how to boil water?*"  I don't see why not.  Maybe people who specialize in cryptography don't use asymptotic arguments every day, much like how bakers don't necessarily boil water every day... but it is in the toolkit of things they ought to be able to do and use to their advantage when needed.

Comment: @DietrichBurde There are explicit lower bounds for such $n$. The same wikipedia page mentions that there is a prime between $n$ and $(1+\tfrac15)n$ for every $n\geq25$. The lower bound claimed in this question then follows easily.

Comment: @kerf The statement is entirely rigorous, and explicit lower bounds for $n$ exist. See also my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

By the prime number theorem, the prime counting function $\pi(n)$ is quite close to

$$\pi(n) \approx \frac{n}{\log n}$$

so

$$\pi(2^{n+1}) - \pi(2^n) \\= \frac{2^{n+1}}{\log 2^{n+1}} - \frac{2^{n}}{\log 2^{n}}\\= \frac{2^n}{\log 2} \left( \frac{2}{n+1} - \frac{1}{n}\right)\\=\frac{2^n}{\log 2} \left( \frac{n-1}{n(n+1)}\right)\\\gg 2 $$

for large $n$.

Comment: But the claim is for all $n\ge 2$, and not just for "large" $n$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde true. in cryptographic context, i suspect though they would be discussing $n$ like $2^{2048}$ or $2^{4096}$ in RSA...

Comment: For "large" $n$ , we supose that ... ; and for "not-large" $n$, we check for each value $n$.

Comment: @Lourrran So for $n=10^{1000}$, did you check then all smaller cases? Your "large" is already really large.

Comment: You can't go from $\approx$ to $=,$ and you need to estimate the error function of $\approx.$ $\approx$ is not really formally defined. But it is a fine heuristical argument

Answer (score 0):

We have certain properties, that have been proven, and other properties, that are totally sure, but not proven. It has been proven that between $n$ and $2 \times n$, we have at least 1 prime. It has not been proven that between $n$ and $1.01 \times n$, for $n > 10^{1000}$, we have at least 1 prime, but if I work on crypto or any science that need primes, I will consider that this property is true. In such an interval, the question is not "is there at least 1 prime ?", but "how many millions of primes ?"

Comment: This is an excellent summary of the difference between pure and applied mathematics or science. Pure mathematics requires proof; applications and science require a preponderance of evidence. That said, I suspect that your particular case *has* been proven, likely for some $n \ll 10^{1000}$